# Right Click ,Left Click and press Enter does not work for searched desktop app result

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search, cortana, windows-10-v1703

Let me describe you the problem briefly by using images.
When I search for old windows app such as **Snipping tool ,Paint** ,etc... through windows 10 search box like this:

[image: search snipping tool][image: search paint]

When I try to right click, normal left click  or even when press **Enter** key nothing happened.But for new windows 10 apps such as Paint3D ,etc... Left,Right clicks and Enter key is working as expected.

[image]

I also noticed that texts within search box were *right aligned*,I didn't configure any windows settings.
The only changed I have done before this critical issue happened is, I installed ubuntu bash(windows subsystem) through Windows Program Add/Remove utilitiy like  this mentioned by microsoft :
[image: Paint 3D]

I cannot figure how does it affect to windows search misbehavior.
Please help me on this matter, if you have any solution other than reinstalling windows 10 it will be great and really appreciated.
I asked this problem from Microsoft few months ago but their solution did not work.
[Microsoft link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/desktop-apps-cannot-started-through-windows-search/1c9c9f99-1182-4f95-b264-a8d0bf1cddc9)

Thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend deleting your post at stackoverflow as it is completely off-topic there and will soon get downvoted. Instead edit your post here with the full text. Also, cross-posting on multiple SE sites is frowned upon.

Comment: thnx for the info.. i cannot post images here.. only 2.. thats why..I posted it in stackoverflow.

Comment: Go ahead and move the complete text over here and I'll add the images for you.

Comment: @n8te since I am not allowed to post links more than 2 .. I put space between *https* protocol text and *//* and bold them ,, it may help you to change them easily.Thank you very much for the editing and cooperation.:)

Comment: Got it. I am working on the edit now. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @n8te thank you for your nice editing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62442/discussion-between-buddhika-chaturanga-and-n8te).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly try to [Kill Process Tree of windows explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9tyv.png) and 
reset icon database cache.

Before going to the final step [run this troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/instantanswers/69e76f90-d54c-44cf-9851-c2d1542790db/run-the-troubleshooter-for-windows-apps) too.
Then

1. Create a new administrator on your Window 10
2. Set privileges to the new Account to access Old account's(issues having) `AppData\Local` directory
3. Sign off from old account and sign in to new admin account
4. Delete  `C:\Users\< OLD_USER_NAME_WITH_ISSUE>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy`
5. Sign back in to OLD user account.
6. Open PowerShell as an admin and input following command:-
   `Add-AppxPackage -Path “C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\Appxmanifest.xml” -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register`

Above solution worked for me.I am using Windows 10 (build 1703) Creators update.

Comment: If only I found this post a few months ago! I had [the same issue](https://superuser.com/q/1205416/643642) as well and the big windows update a few days ago fixed it so I wanted to remove mine and found yours in the related questions. I cannot validate it but it looks good. You got my vote and hopefully I will find this if it is messed up for me again!